# Add header html file with javascript

Tags: javascript

thi is javascript code to show another html file inside index.html

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script> 
$(function(){
$("#header").load("header.html"); 
$("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
});
</script> 

<div id="header"></div>
<!--Remaining section-->
<div id="footer"></div>
```

but how to make when i click example header to show just content of header.html or if i click footer to show just footer.html

```
       <li><a href="header.html"><span>Header</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="footer.html"><span>Footer</span></a></li>
```

Comment: If you want to switch to another HTML page with JavaScript, you can do it this way: window.location.href = "header.html"; (called a redirect).

Comment: i want to add content of other html file inside my html file

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="header.html" data-container="header">
            <span>Header</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="footer.html" data-container="footer">
            <span>Footer</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="header"></div>
<!--Remaining section-->
<div id="footer"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#nav li a').on('click', function() {
        var el = $(this);
        $('#' + el.data('container')).load(el.attr('href'));
        return false;
    });    
});
```

Comment: it show both header and footer when u click on them.
it need to show just that u click 
so if u click header will show just header and after that if u click footer will show just footer

Comment: @Arlinda understood you now. Well, I'd do like this http://jsfiddle.net/te6067ps/1/